# Внесение значение в RichTextBox из файла и обратно

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы программа автоматически вносила изменения в файл. На C# я посмотрел, код такой:

```
RichTextBox1.LoadFile(@"D:\Записи.txt",RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

А вот в VB, я пытался сделать тоже самое, но не получается. Файл создается, но записи в нём не появляются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При загрузке

```
rtb.LoadFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

При любом изменении

```
Private Sub rtb_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rtb.TextChanged
    rtb.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
End Sub
```

При выгрузке

```
rtb.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.